# Empathy chat limits the number of contacts displayed?

Tags: empathy

I'm using Empathy Chat with these accounts: GTalk & Facebook.

I just noticed now that from my GTalk friends only 6 appear online (including me) and in reality online are 14 (checked on GMail). And from Facebook it displays 44.

So is Empathy Chat limited to display only 50 contacts? I looked through the settings and didn't see anything like this :|

The worst part is that I have 1 GTalk contact as Favorite and it's not in the list... Is it a bug?

PS: I'm using Ubuntu 10.10

Comment: Can you turn on display offline buddies

Comment: are these people actually online, or just on your contact list? By default you won't see offline contacts.

Comment: @karthick87 if I display online+offline users, I can see the full list

Comment: @Roland Taylor they were online :(

Comment: well I've not had this problem, so I would suggest reporting a bug on empathy (`ubuntu-bug empathy`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that there is a bug in empathy, you can report this issue by either from a command line executing the following command:

`ubuntu-bug empathy`

Or going to the empathy bug tracker and reporting the problem directly:

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=empathy

This direct route is more likely to get a response from the developers and sooner. Please provide all information including which version of empathy you're using.